# Slow Regular Expression Performance

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have a table that I need to parse using a large regular expression.  The table is actually a script and the regular expression ensures that keywords in the script are correctly formed and sequenced.

A typical script line (as opposed to the regex) contains expressions separated by a single | character.  Groups of expressions are organized using a triple pipe separator '|||' separator.

The [regexr](http://regexr.com/3c578) example contains an example of 1 row in the table to which I apply the worst case scenario regular expression.  The regular expression works fine, however it is a bottleneck in my application and I suspect that this is due to all the backtracking in the regex engine.  I've been experimenting with greedy vs non greedy but so far tweaking the regex and profiling it in my application has made minimal effect.

Could someone suggest a way that I could restructure my regex to yield better results.  I presume that the backtracking is the reason for the slow performance but I am not sure.

Comment: The example has unmatched parentheses.

Comment: thanks Charles, I just updated it, there was some problem making a permalink - check the updated link http://regexr.com/3c578

Comment: Can you please provide us an example of input and expected output?

Comment: at first removing capture groups reduces steps by a lot

Comment: just look at https://regex101.com/r/gT1iT9/1

Comment: @Doro, thanks - good suggestion, however I forgot to mention that I need the capturing groups as I need to extract them from the regex search results.  The idea is that while parsing a sentence the first capture group is a primitive and other following ones are associated parameters (the numbef of which varies depending on the primitive) the SETCNTX primitive is the worst case scenario one.

Comment: Yes, I can't believe you need all those capturing groups. The entire regexp match (group #1) for example. And a lot of those alternative capture groups are coming out null aren't they (#4, #5, #6, #9, etc.)?

Comment: Yes this is true, but that is because I was only applying a partial regular expression that only searches for the SETCNTX sentences.  The way I actually use the regex would be more similar to using it as follows - where I added alternate captures to capture the missing FTPNOPROMPT, FTPCLOSE and WAIT sentences - check out the http://regexr.com/3c578